# Webpack: prebuild lifecycle hook for libraries

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs, rollupjs, parceljs

I'm the author of a library and I need a script to be run each time before webpack bundles my library into the user's app code.

My library's `package.json` would be something like this:

```json
{
  "name": "some-js-library",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "scripts": {
    "prebuild": "./path/to/my-libs-prebuild-script.js"
  }
}
```

The user's `package.json` could be anything, for example:

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "//": "or however the user uses webpack",
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "some-js-library": "^0.1.0"
  }
}
```

I don't have any control over my users' `package.json`, so I'm left to wonder if it's possible to have `my-libs-prebuild-script.js` executed every time before webpack starts building?

Ideally this would be a standard that every bundler agrees on, but a webpack only solution would be fine.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think there's a supported way to modify the users Webpack configuration from an external library, with good reason. What specifically does your prebuild script do?

Comment: it runs `git shortlog` to check how many Git authors the user's repo has. My library needs this information. When my library is consumed in a Node.js context that's not a problem. But when it used on the browser-side then I need to pass that info from build-time to runtime.